# Can we add only the unique columns into the tuple while solving problem through column generation appraoch?

Tags: cplex, opl

Adding only unique columns into the tuple.

I am trying to add the columns into the tuple in column generation after solving the sub problem and using the pool of solutions. I see that in my problem same columns are added multiple times. Is there a way to only add unique columns in the data(or tuple)? 
I have taken the code from the cutting stock problem. Can someone please explain me editing in this code?

```
writeln("Solve sub.");
  if ( subCplex.solve() &&
       subCplex.getObjValue() <= -RC_EPS) {
    writeln();
    writeln("SUB OBJECTIVE: ",subCplex.getObjValue());
masterData.Patterns.add(masterData.Patterns.size+1, subOpl.Select.solutionValue;
  } else {
    writeln("No new good pattern, stop.");

subCplex.solnPoolIntensity = 3; 
find larger no. of solutions

subCplex.populate();
var nsolns = subCplex.solnPoolNsolns;
for (var v = 1; v<=nsolns; v++) {
    subOpl.setPoolSolution(v);

    if(subCplex.getObjValue(v) <= -1.0e-10) {       
    masterData.Patterns.add(masterData.Patterns.size+1,subOpl.Select.solutionValue;
  }  

}

 masterData.Patterns.add(masterData.Patterns.size,1,subOpl.Use.solutionValue);
  masterOpl = new IloOplModel(masterDef,masterCplex);
  masterOpl.addDataSource(masterData);
  masterOpl.generate();
  // End sub model
     subData.end();
  subOpl.end();
```

}

Comment: CPLEX don't have a function to do that. You need to create a data structure by yourself that stores all input columns and verify if they are repeated or not.

Comment: You may want to turn this comment into an answer: I would upvote it...

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, Iago.

Answer (score 2):

CPLEX don't have a function to do that. You need to create a data structure by yourself that stores all input columns and verify if they are repeated or not. – Iago Carvalho